# outdoor RaspberryPi streaming video access by others with phones and such

Tags: wifi, video, streaming

I want to attach my already setup, video streaming web server Pi to my kite and allow others in the close proximity to view the video via an IP address. There obviously won't be any kind of commercial wi-fi service available so I assume I will have to create my own.

I tried making this all work using only one Pi, but I think I need to use another Pi.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you just make your pi dual-homed and setup a dhcp server. Basically just make it an access point so anyone within range can connect, they will then be assigned an ip address and then connect to the video files over Samba, NFS or something along those lines?

[Here](http://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point.pdf) is a pretty detailed tutorial on how to setup the pi as an access point.

[Here](http://tech.theswamp.in/post/2013/02/16/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-powered-headless-media-server-and-nas/) is a decent tutorial on how to setup pi as a headless media server.

Google will be your friend if you ask nicely :)

Comment: Found the perfect tutorial [here](http://www.daveconroy.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-router-and-web-server/)  Thanks!!!!